# Cannot compute collision and compare times in Hash search

Tags: c++, hashtable, hash-collision

there. I am trying to get collision and compare times in Hash search. Yet it doesn't work out. Can anyone point out what the problem is? Thanks very much. Here is my code.

### HashSerch.cpp

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

const int TOTAL=32;    //32 keywords
const int MAXLEN=10;   //length of keyword
const int HASHLEN=41;  //length of HASH table
const char* KeyWords[TOTAL] = 
{
    "auto","double","int","struct","break","else","long","switch",
    "case","enum","register","typedef","char","extern","return","union",
    "const","float","short","unsigned","continue","for","signed","void",
    "default","goto","sizeof","volatile","do","if","while","static",
};

class HASH
{
public:
    char keyword[MAXLEN];
    int count;     //occurrence number
    int con;       //collision times
};
HASH HS[HASHLEN];


//declaration
int isLetter(char ch);
int isKeyWords(char *word);
int FindHX(char *keyword);     //search Hash table
int CreatHX(char *keyword);    //create Hash table
int GetFreePos(int key);       //get free position when having collision
void ResetHX();
int GetKey(char *keyword);    //get Hash value of keywords
int ShowHashTable(int key);     //show search results

int isLetter(char ch)
{
    if( (ch>='a'&&ch<='z')||(ch>='A'&&ch<='Z') ) return 1;
    else return 0;
} 

int FindHX(char *keyword, int &cmp_count)   //search Hash table
{
    int key,find,tem=0;
    if(!isKeyWords(keyword)) return -1;
    key=GetKey(keyword);  

    if(strcmp(HS[key].keyword,keyword)==0)
    {
        cmp_count++;
        return key;
    }

    for(find=key+1;find<HASHLEN;find++)    //if keyword exsits
    {       
        cmp_count++;  //count compare times         
        tem++;      //count collision times
        if(strcmp(HS[find].keyword,keyword)==0)
        {
            HS[find].con=tem;
            return find;
        }
    }   

    for(find=0;find<key;find++)
    {
        cmp_count++;
        tem++;
        if(strcmp(HS[find].keyword,keyword)==0)
        {
            HS[find].con=tem;
            return find; 
        }
    }   
    return -1;
} 

int CreatHX(char *keyword)  //create Hash table
{
    int key;
    if(!isKeyWords(keyword)) return -1; 
    key=GetKey(keyword); //get Hash value of keywords

    if(strlen(HS[key].keyword)>0)    //if the keyword exists
    {    
        if(strcmp(HS[key].keyword,keyword)==0) //if equals to position in Hash table
        {
            HS[key].count++;
            return 1;
        }
        key=FindHX(keyword, cmp_count);  //not equal
        if(key<0)
        {
            key=GetFreePos(GetKey(keyword));
            if(key<0) return -1;
            strcpy(HS[key].keyword,keyword);  //insert keyword into Hash table
        }

        if(key<0) return -1;
        HS[key].count++;
    }
    else  //if position is empty, insert keyword 
    {
        strcpy(HS[key].keyword,keyword);
        HS[key].count++;
    }
    return 1;
}

int GetFreePos(int key)  //get free position
{
    int find,tem=0;
    if(key<0||key>=HASHLEN) return -1;
    for(find=key+1;find<HASHLEN;find++)  //positions afterwards
    {
        tem++;
        if(strlen(HS[find].keyword)==0)
        {
            HS[find].con=tem;
            return find; 
        }
    }

    for(find=0;find<key;find++)  //position forewards
    {
        tem++;
        if(strlen(HS[find].keyword)==0)
        {
            HS[find].con=tem;
            return find; 
        }
    }
    return -1;     //Hash table is full
}

void ResetHX()  
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<HASHLEN;i++)
    {
        strcpy(HS[i].keyword,""); 
        HS[i].count=0;
        HS[i].con=0;
    }
} 

int GetKey(char *keyword)  //get Hash value of keywords
{ 
    //Hash(Key)=[(initial letter)*100+(tail letter)] Mod 41
    return ( keyword[0]*100+keyword[strlen(keyword)-1] ) % 41; 
} 

int isKeyWords(char *word) 
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<TOTAL;i++)
    if(strcmp(word,KeyWords[i])==0) return 1; 
    return 0;
} 

int ShowHashTable(int key)  //show results
{
    int hash_count = 0;
    if(key < 0 || key >= HASHLEN)
    {
        cout << "Error! Invalid key word!" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    if(strlen(HS[key].keyword) == 0)
    {
        cout << "[" << key << "]" << setw(12) << "N/A" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    cout << "[" << key << "]" << setw(12) << HS[key].keyword << setw(12) << "Count: " << HS[key].count << endl;
    hash_count++;
    return hash_count;
}
```

### main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include "HashSearch.h"
extern HASH HS[MAXLEN];
using namespace std;

int hash_count = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < HASHLEN; i++)
{
    hash_count = hash_count + ShowHashTable(i); 
}
cout << "Amount of key words: " << hash_count << endl << endl;

int conf_count = 0;
cout << setiosflags(ios::left) << setw(15) << "[Index]" << setiosflags(ios::left) << setw(20)
    << "[KeyWords]" << setiosflags(ios::left) << setw(20) << "[Conflicts]" << endl;

for(int i = 0; i < HASHLEN; i++)
{
    if(strlen(HS[i].keyword) > 0)
    {
        int key = Hash(HS[i].keyword);
        if(key != i)
        {
            conf_count++;
            //cout << HS[i].con << endl;
            cout << setiosflags(ios::left) << setw(15) << i << setiosflags(ios::left) << setw(25)   
                << HS[i].keyword << setiosflags(ios::left) << setw(20) << HS[i].con << endl;
        }
    }
}
if(conf_count == 0) 
    cout << "No conflicts!" << endl;
else
    cout << "Amount of conflict keywords: " << conf_count << endl << endl;
```

---

I first imported a source txt file and created a Hash table. It seems that all goes well. But when I want to get the compare times and collision times, the variable HS.con(to count collision times) and cmp_count(to count compare times) don't accumulate correctly. The value stays 0 if watching in debug mode. And how can I get correct count?

Comment: I don't know if you're using a global, but in the line `key = FindHX(keyword, cmp_count);  //not equal` in the function `int CreatHX(char *keyword)  //create Hash table`, the variable `cmp_count` is never declared/defined. From what you say, it sounds like your full code compiles, so you must define it somewhere outside of the code you've given, but that may indicate where your issue lies.

Comment: yes, I defined global variable cmp_count in main function and pass it to FindHX and CreateHX.